# How to refresh Access token from Azure AD application in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm, access-token

I have this azure AD app that sends data from an email to a board in monday.com, but the problem is that the Access token that gives me access to the azure ad app, expires every 1 hour, so i have to manually put a new access token for it to work again, but how do i make the code auto refresh the access token when it expires?

This code below works, it fetch the latest email then sends it to monday, and every 10 seconds it checks again to see if there is a new email.

But the problem is that like i said every hour the access token expires so i have to manually change it in the .env file.

Is there a way to auto-refresh it?

````
const { Client } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");
const { request } = require('graphql-request');
require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');



const endpoint = process.env.MONDAY_ENDPOINT;
const MondayApiKey = process.env.MONDAY_API_KEY;
const boardId = parseInt(process.env.MONDAY_BOARD_ID); 
const lastEmailFile = process.env.LAST_EMAIL;



setInterval(() => {

    let lastEmailId = '';
  try {
    lastEmailId = fs.readFileSync(lastEmailFile, 'utf8').trim();
  } catch (err) {}

    // Initialize Graph client
    const client = Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
            // Call getToken function to get access token
            getToken((err, token) => {
                if (err) {
                    done(err);
                } else {
                    done(null, token);
                }
            });
        },
    });

    // Fetch newest emails from the user's Inbox folder
    client.api("/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages")
        .top(1)
        .select("subject,from,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview")
        .orderby("receivedDateTime DESC")
        .get((err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } 
            else {
                const email = res.value[0];

                if (email.id !== lastEmailId) {
                    // Store the email id in file
                    fs.writeFileSync(lastEmailFile, email.id);
              

                    //Les variables qui contient la data du email
                    const EmailSubject = res.value[0].subject;
                    const EmailFrom =  res.value[0].from.emailAddress;
                    const EmailRecievedDate = res.value[0].receivedDateTime;
                    const EmailBody = res.value[0].bodyPreview;
                    const IsRead = res.value[0].isRead;

                    //Sends data to MONDAY
                    const itemName = EmailSubject;
                    const itemText = EmailFrom.address;
                    const variables = { boardId, itemName,itemText};

                    const mutation = `
                    mutation ($boardId: Int!, $itemName:String!) {
                        create_item (board_id: $boardId, item_name: $itemName, column_values: "{\\"texte\\": \\"${itemText}\\"}") {
                            id
                            name
                        }
                    }
                    `;

                    request(endpoint, mutation, variables, {
                        'Authorization': MondayApiKey
                        }).then(data => {
                            console.log(data);
                        }).catch(err => {
                            console.log(err);
                    });


                    console.log('From :' +res.value[0].from.emailAddress);
                    console.log('Subject :' +  res.value[0].subject);
                    console.log('BodyPreview :' +  res.value[0].bodyPreview);
                    console.log('EmailRecievedDate :' +  res.value[0].receivedDateTime);
                    //console.log(res.value); //Afficher le data du email
                }
            }

            console.log('No New Emails');
        });

}, 10000); //Chaque 10 secondes il y a une vérification

     //Function to get access token
     function getToken(callback) {
       // Code to get access token  
       const OutlookaAccessToken = process.env.OUTLOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN;
       callback(null, OutlookaAccessToken);
     }```
````

Comment: you should use their oauth endpoints in your code

Comment: @DanielA.White do you have an example on how to do that?